How can I display line by line using \pause or \onslide on Beamer for this code
\begin{scope}       
            \clip (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (7.5,4.5);
            % Series of lines all through point A
            \foreach \xN/\yN [count=\i] in {6.5/3.2,6/2.38,5.5/1.7,5/1.18,4.5/0.8,4/0.58,3.5/0.5}
             {
                \coordinate (N) at (\xN,\yN);
                \tkzDrawPoint[size=8](N)
                \tkzDrawLine[add=2 and 3,color=red](A,N)
                }              
        \end{scope} 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My code allows drawing multiple lines using the loop (\foreach), and the code works fine. But when I tried to make a presentation where I would like to display one line at a time, I couldn’t do it on Beamer, even though I tried using the \pause or \onslide commands

Can you please create a minimal example showing a complete minimal document that we can actually compile?

@MarsoSaid Guessing what packages you might use is much harder than actually solving your problem. If you want to speed things up, save us from having to guess and we can directly go to the solving your problem part.

I apologize for the poor wording of my question. Below, I have included my entire code with which I would like to display the lines one by one in presentation mode.

@MarsoSaid please edit your question instead. The space below is reserved for solutions.

You could use an uncover environment to gradually reveal the lines:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw (-1,0) -- (7.5,0) (0,-.5) -- (0,4.5); % Axis
         \node[below left=2pt and 2pt] at (0,0) {$O$}; % Origin 
        % Function curve        
        \begin{scope}       
            \clip (-1,0) rectangle (7.5,4.5);
            \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=blue,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.5:7.5] plot(\x,{0.3*((\x)-3.5)*((\x)-3.5)+0.5}); 
        \end{scope}
        \def\xA{2.5} \def\yA{0.8}
        \coordinate (A) at (\xA,\yA);
        \draw[dashed] (\xA,0) node[below=2pt] {$a$} -- (A) -- (0,\yA) node[left] {$f(a)$};   
        \def\xM{6.5} \def\yM{3.2}
        \coordinate (M) at (\xM,\yM);
        \draw[dashed] (\xM,0) node[below] {$x$} -- (M) -- (0,\yM) node[left] {$f(x)$};
        \tkzDrawPoints[size=8](A,M)
        \tkzLabelPoint[above=3pt](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above left](M){$M$}
        %%%%%%%%%%%  %%%%Arrows alongside the curve
         \foreach \a/\b in {6.55/6.9, 6/6.35, 5.5/5.85, 4.9/5.35, 4.35/4.75}
            {
            \draw[<-,>=stealth,line width=1pt,color=orange,smooth,samples=100,domain=\a:\b] plot(\x,{0.32*((\x)-3.95)*((\x)-3.95)+0.55});
            }
   %%%%%%  multiple lines    
             \begin{scope}       
            \clip (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (7.5,4.5);
            % Series of lines all through point A
            \foreach \xN/\yN in {6.5/3.2,6/2.38,5.5/1.7,5/1.18,4.5/0.8,4/0.58,3.5/0.5}
             {
              \begin{visibleenv}<+->
                  \coordinate (N) at (\xN,\yN);
                  \tkzDrawPoint[size=8](N)
                  \tkzDrawLine[add=2 and 3,color=red](A,N)
              \end{visibleenv}
                }              
        \end{scope}      
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}


